# Como substituir os parametros iguais a primeira ocorrencia começando da segunda ocorrencia na mesmo frase em python

Tags: python, for, replace

Quero mudar todas as letras de uma ocorrência em Python, porém a partir da 2 posição o código que eu fiz é:

```
nome = str(input(('Digite um nome: ')))
for letra in (nome):
   print(nome.replace(nome[0],'*')) # aqui substituo por * todos que forem igual nome na posição 0
```

palavra = `abacate`
Resultado esperado = `ab*c*te`

Comment: Entendi, nesse caso naturalmente o input retorna string sem precisar converter e o for não é necessário, dei uma olhada no exemplo e funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 1):

Primeira coisa a se observar é linha:

```
nome = str(input(('Digite um nome: ')))
```

O uso da função [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#func-str) é desnecessário pois o resultado da função [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#input) será um uma string, veja a documentação:

> *`input([prompt])`*
> Se o argumento prompt estiver presente, escreve na saída padrão sem uma nova >linha ao final. **A função então lê uma linha da fonte de entrada, converte a
> mesma para uma string** (removendo o caractere de nova linha ao final), e >devolve isso.

Também há um excesso de parêntesis. A linha poderia ser escrita como:

```
nome = input('Digite um nome: ')
```

Respondendo a pergunta, o uso do laço de iteração `for` junto da função [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) não é melhor caminho pois o laço de iteração como projetado irá iterar individualmente por cada caractere da entrada enquanto por sua vez `str.replace()` retorna uma cópia da string com a substituição de todas as ocorrências de uma substring específica.

Caso queira deixar de lado as soluções iterativas use `str.replace()`:

```
nome = "abacate"                                    #nome = input('Digite um nome: ')
resultado = nome[0] + nome[1:].replace(nome[0],'*') #resultado recebe a primeira letra de nome o resultado da função str.replace() substituindo do segundo ao último caractere de nome o caractere em nome[0] por *.                            
print(resultado) 
#ab*c*te
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo acima no [IdeOne](https://ideone.com/L6xnje)</sup>

Caso queira seguir o caminho da iteração por caracteres são várias as opções:

- Manipulando strings onde o resultado recebe o primeiro caractere da palavra e em seguida itere do segundo ao último caractere comparando o caractere iterado com o primeiro, adicionando um asterisco ao resultado caso sejam iguais serão adicione a letra ao resultado:

```
nome = "abacate"                                   #nome = input('Digite um nome: ')
resultado = nome[0]                                #Inicializa o resultado com o primeiro caractere de nome.
for c in (nome[1:]):                               #Do segundo ao último caractere de nome em c...
  resultado += '*' if c == nome[0] else c          #Se c==nome[0] adicione * ao resultado senão adicione o caractere em c ao resultado. 

print(resultado)                                   #Imprime o resultado
#ab*c*te
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo acima no [IdeOne](https://ideone.com/eZKkSc)</sup>

- Manipulando uma listas, é mesmo raciocínio anterior só que desta vez o resultado é uma lista que receberá os caracteres e ao final a lista contendo o resultado é unida numa string com a função [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

```
nome = "abacate"                                        #nome = input('Digite um nome: ')
resultado = [nome[0]]                                   #Inicializa o resultado com o primeiro elemento o primeiro caractere de nome.
for c in (nome[1:]):                                    #Do segundo ao último caractere de nome em c...
  resultado.append( '*' if letra == nome[0] else letra) #Se c==nome[0] adicione * ao resultado senão adicione o caractere em c ao resultado. 

print("".join(resultado))                               #Junta todos elementos da lista resultado numa string e imprime.
#ab*c*te
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo acima no [IdeOne](https://ideone.com/Z8aaaA)</sup>

- Usando compreensão de listas ainda é mesmo raciocínio só realizado de forma mais compacta:

```
nome = "abacate"
resultado = [nome[0]]+['*' if c == nome[0] else c for c in (nome[1:])]

print("".join(resultado))
#ab*c*te
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo acima no [IdeOne](https://ideone.com/B1IM19)</sup>

- Usando as características funcionais do python, com a função nativa [map()](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#map) pode-se aplicar uma função anônima de comparação substituição aos caracteres:

```
nome = "abacate"
resultado = "".join([nome[0],*map(lambda c: '*' if c == nome[0] else c, nome[1:])])
print(resultado) 
#ab*c*te
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo acima no [IdeOne](https://ideone.com/djw9AY)</sup>

Comment: A solução com `str.replace` deveria estar no topo dessa resposta.

Comment: @sourcream, agradeço a sugestão. Fiz a alteração propósta.